# LINQ - Query Children Object If Parent Count is = 1

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a the following Class structure.

```
Company > List(of Departments) > List(of Employees)
```

I want to Query a Company to find out if it has a department of the following name and a Employee in that department with the following ID!

How could I query this. The way I have the code it expect to return one department so I have it doing

```
If Company.Where(function(d) d.Name = 'ABC').First.Where(function(e) e.EmployeeId = 1).Count > 0
```

But this will error
 `if d.Name = 'ABC'` returns 0 records (I expect it to return 1 or 0 records!)

Is it possible to do this in one `linq` statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assuming that a company has multiple departments and a department has multiple employees-- then you could do this.. sorry I'm not using vb syntax:

```
DB.Departments.Where(d=>d.Name=="ABC").SelectMany(d=>d.Employees).Any(e=>e.EmployeeId == 7)
```

this would tell you if a specific employee was in a specific department name at any of the companies.

Answer (score 2):

```
var employeeExists = (from company in companies
   where company.Name = expectedCompanyName
   from department in company.Departments
   from employee in department.Employees
   where employee.Id == expectedEmployeeId
   select employee.Id).Any()
```